# Fancybox not working - any advice?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Helo! I am trying to implement Fancybox and I can't get it to work.

Here's what I have in my head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("$fancybox").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none'
    });
});


</script>
```

And here is what I have in my page:

```
    <a class="fancybox" href="../js/fancybox/source/fancybox_loading.gif" title="See Pricing">See Pricing</a>
```

I am actually wanting to get fancybox to display a div, but I can't even get it to display an image.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: This `$("$fancybox")` seems like a syntax error. If you are binding an ID it should be `$("#fancybox")` but if you are binding a CSS class then it should be `$(".fancybox")`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I was trying to figure out I should use the . or what...but your explanation worked. I changed it to # and in the link, I changed it to id="fancybox". All is well now. Thanks!

Comment: Just bear in mind that IDs should be unique (only one element can have that ID) ... if you want to bind several elements to fancybox use classes (the `.` [dot]) instead