# Fancybox displaying dynamic inline content

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I am implementing Fancybox onto my page. My goal is to have a button that says 'pricing options', and when clicked, a Fancybox pops up that has the item's prices, which are contained in a php database.

The page itself generates the items also from the same php database.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="pager clearfix">
    <?php $recorded_courses=$ courses->get_courses(); ?>
    <?php foreach($recorded_courses as $key=>$course) : ?>
    <div class="course-grid2 grid"> <a href="<?php echo $course['course_id']; ?>.html">
            <img src="<?php echo $course['course_id']; ?>/box.png" width="180" height="180" alt="<?php echo $course['title']; ?>" title="Learn more">
        </a>
        <h3><a href="<?php echo $course['course_id']; ?>.html"><?php echo $course['title']; ?></a></h3>
        <p class="short-description">
            <?php echo $course[ 'summary']; ?>with <b><?php echo $course['instructors']; ?></b>
        </p>
        <p class="small">
            <?php echo $course[ 'format']; ?>
        </p>
        <div class="links"> <a href="<?php echo $course['course_id']; ?>.html">Learn more</a>   <a id="fancybox" href="#content-div" title="See Pricing">See Pricing</a>
            <div style="display: none">
                <div id="content-div" style="width:250px;height:400px;overflow:auto;">
                        <h3><a href="<?php echo $course['course_id']; ?>.html"><?php echo $course['title']; ?></a></h3>

                    <?php echo $course[ 'summary']; ?>with <b><?php echo $course['instructors']; ?></b>
                    <p style="font-size:x-small">
                        <br> <strong> DVDs only:</strong> 
                        <?php echo $courses->display_price2($course['price'], $course['price2']); ?>
                        <?php echo $courses->cart_form($course['cart_title'] . ' - ' . $course['instructors'], $course['price'], $course['course_id'], 'recorded-courses'); ?></p>
                    <p style="font-size:x-small">
                        <br><strong> Online only:</strong> 
                        <?php echo $courses->display_price3($course['price3'], $course['price4']); ?>   <a href="<?php echo $course['moodle_id']; ?>"> Enroll Now </a>
                    </p>
                    <p style="font-size:x-small">
                        <br> <strong> Online + DVDs:</strong> 
                    </p>
                    <p style="font-size:x-small">
                        <?php echo $courses->display_price4($course['price5'], $course['price6']); ?>   <a href="<?php echo $course['moodle_id']; ?>"> Enroll & Purchase Now </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fancybox").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none'
    });
});
</script>
```

What happens, though, is the Fancybox window opens, and it always displays the prices for the first item, regardless of which item was selected by the customer.

So for some reason, the div/Fancybox is ignoring which 'Pricing Options' button was clicked. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason *the Fancybox window opens, and it always displays the prices for the first item, regardless of which item was selected by the customer.*

```
<a id="fancybox" href="#content-div" title="See Pricing">See Pricing</a>
<div style="display: none">
    <div id="content-div" style="width:250px;height:400px;overflow:auto;">Content</div>
</div>
```

Fancy box and it's call button both inside the loop and target id is same so it will always Only show the first row record from database.

**Solution**

Give the dynamic id to fancybox target button and fancybox selector

e.g assuming that you can fetch id from database `<?php echo $course['id']; ?>`

```
<a id="fancybox" href="#content-div<?php echo $course['id'];?>" title="See Pricing">See Pricing</a>
<div style="display: none">
    <div id="content-div<?php echo $course['id'];?>" style="width:250px;height:400px;overflow:auto;">Content</div>
</div>
```

Suppose for first item `id=1` and for second item `id=2` so in loop fancybox and it's call button will be like this

for `id=1`

```
<a id="fancybox" href="#content-div1" title="See Pricing">See Pricing</a>
<div style="display: none">
    <div id="content-div1" style="width:250px;height:400px;overflow:auto;">Content</div>
</div>
```

and for `id=2`

```
<a id="fancybox" href="#content-div2" title="See Pricing">See Pricing</a>
<div style="display: none">
    <div id="content-div2" style="width:250px;height:400px;overflow:auto;">Content</div>
</div>
```

Side Note: @JFK suggested to use class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447356/fancybox-not-working-any-advice) in comments, reasons are

[HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) says ID must be document-wide unique.

[HTML 5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) says the same thing but in other words. It says that ID must be unique in its home subtree, which is basically the document if we read the definition of it.

So also make changes here

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none'
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#content-div<?php echo $course['id'];?>" title="See Pricing">See Pricing</a>
<div style="display: none">
    <div id="content-div<?php echo $course['id'];?>" style="width:250px;height:400px;overflow:auto;">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs should be unique, so you shouldn't use the same ID for more than a single element in the same document. Use classes instead

Comment: @JFK can you point me in answer where I even suggest AND using same ID?

Comment: If you understood the question, you are implicitly suggesting that (hint: links are generated inside a `foreach` loop) ... you even suggest to change the ID of the target element but not the trigger element

Comment: @JFK `Give the dynamic id to fancybox target button and fancybox selector`

Comment: Yes, you said that but is not reflected in the code (which still uses the same `id="fancybox"`)

Comment: @JFK lol `id="fancybox"` is basically calling the fancybox `$("#fancybox").fancybox({`

Comment: so you are giving me the reason ;)

Comment: @JKF I'm tired and don't wana to go in  discussion but be my guest and provide a solution where assign dynamic ids to fancybox calling function and here too `    $("#fancybox").fancybox({
            'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none'
      
     });` becuase i know how fancybox works and i know the problem OP was having with the data inside fancybox not with the fancybox, fancybox is just a popup it's not fancybox job to get the right data against right id

Comment: @JFK I updated the answer and i have done this the other day if you have just narrow down the problem just to fancybox call function id, what i thought was you are trying to say my solution with dynamic ids are wrong and should use classes, (deleting all the above comments)